# Why 'T.super.toString()' and 'super::toString' use a synthetic accessor method?

Tags: java, java-8, super, method-reference, synthetic

Consider the following set of expressions:

```
class T {{
/*1*/   super.toString();      // direct
/*2*/   T.super.toString();    // synthetic
        Supplier<?> s;
/*3*/   s = super::toString;   // synthetic
/*4*/   s = T.super::toString; // synthetic
}}
```

Which gives the following result:

```
class T {
    T();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [8]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  invokespecial java.lang.Object.toString() : java.lang.String [10]
     8  pop           // ^-- direct
     9  aload_0 [this]
    10  invokestatic T.access$0(T) : java.lang.String [14]
    13  pop           // ^-- synthetic
    14  aload_0 [this]
    15  invokedynamic 0 get(T) : java.util.function.Supplier [21]
    20  astore_1 [s]  // ^-- methodref to synthetic
    21  aload_0 [this]
    22  invokedynamic 1 get(T) : java.util.function.Supplier [22]
    27  astore_1      // ^-- methodref to synthetic
    28  return

    static synthetic java.lang.String access$0(T arg0);
    0  aload_0 [arg0]
    1  invokespecial java.lang.Object.toString() : java.lang.String [10]
    4  areturn

    Bootstrap methods:
    0 : # 40 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:...
        #43 invokestatic T.access$0:(LT;)Ljava/lang/String;
    1 : # 40 invokestatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:...
        #46 invokestatic T.access$0:(LT;)Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

**Why** java code lines `/*2*/`, `/*3*/` and `/*4*/` **produce and use a synthetic accessor method** `access$0`? I would expect the line `/*2*/` and bootstrap methods for lines `/*3*/` and `/*4*/` to also use `invokespecial` as the line `/*1*/` does.

Especially when the method `Object::toString` is accessible directly from the relevant scope, e.g. the following method reference doesn't wrap a call to a synthetic accessor method:

```
class F {{
    Function<Object, ?> f = Object::toString; // direct
}}
```

However, there **is** a difference:

```
class O {{
        super.toString();      // invokespecial -> "className@hashCode"
        O.super.toString();    // invokespecial -> "className@hashCode"
        Supplier<?> s;
        s = super::toString;   // invokespecial -> "className@hashCode"
        s = O.super::toString; // invokespecial -> "className@hashCode"
        Function<Object, ?> f = Object::toString;
        f.apply(O.super); // invokeinterface -> "override"
    }
    public String toString() {return "override";}
}
```

Which brings another question: Is there a way how to bypass an override in `((Function<Object, ?> Object::toString)::apply`?

Comment: Note that the behavior of a lambda expression is fixed and can't be altered by the invoker. Hence, the invalid (but accepted by Eclipse) syntax `f.apply(O.super);` can't make a difference to `f.apply(O.this);` as it's the same object and the invocation behavior is fixed for this function. You can't create a `Function<Object, ?>` that ignores overrides (with legal Java constructs), but you can create a `Function<O, ?>` that ignores overrides, using a helper method, similar to these synthetic `access$n` methods.

Comment: Tested. A `((Function<O, ?>) O::helper).apply(this)` where `private String helper() {return super.toString();}` works fine. However, it works only 1 level up, and unless you create a chain of helpers up the hierarchy, you'll never get a hold of the real `Object::toString`, right? Thanks anyway.

Comment: For inner classes, when the helper is `private String helper() {return OuterMostClass.super.toString();}` it will still only call the parent of the `OuterMostClass`, not `Object`, so it seems there is no plain java way.

Comment: ...where a simple `invokespecial` would do...

Comment: No, that was long ago, when `invokespecial` allowed to skip/target arbitrary classes (Java 1.0). Nowadays, for non-`private`, non-`interface` methods the target type must be the direct superclass of the containing class. Otherwise, the verifier is entitled to reject it. There was a time when the absence of the `ACC_SUPER` flag could reinforce the old behavior, but the most recent JVMs treat all classes like if the flag is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An invocation of the form `super.method()` allows to bypass an overriding `method()` in the same class, invoking the most specific `method()` of the super class hierarchy. Since, on the byte code level, only the declaring class itself can ignore its own overriding method (and potential overriding methods of subclasses), a synthetic accessor method will be generated if this kind of invocation should be performed by a different (but conceptionally entitled) class, like one of its inner classes, using the form `Outer.super.method(...)`, or a synthetic class generated for a method reference.

Note that even if a class doesn't override the invoked method and it seems to make no difference, the invocation has to be compiled this way as there could be subclasses at runtime overriding the method and then, it will make a difference.

It's interesting that the same thing happens when using `T.super.method()` when `T` actually isn't an outer class but the class containing the statement. In that case, the helper method isn't really necessary, but it seems that the compiler implements all invocations of the form `identifier.super.method(...)` uniformly.

---

As a side note, Oracle's JRE is capable of circumventing this byte code restriction when generating classes for lambda expressions/method references, thus, the accessor methods are not needed for method references of the `super::methodName` kind, which can be shown as follows:

```
import java.lang.invoke.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class LambdaSuper {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
        MethodType mt=MethodType.methodType(String.class);
        MethodHandle target=l.findSpecial(Object.class, "toString", mt, LambdaSuper.class);
        Supplier<String> s=(Supplier)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "get",
            MethodType.methodType(Supplier.class, LambdaSuper.class),
            mt.generic(), target, mt).getTarget().invokeExact(new LambdaSuper());
        System.out.println(s.get());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "overridden method";
    }
}
```

The generated `Supplier` will return something alike `LambdaSuper@6b884d57` showing that it invoked the overridden `Object.toString()` method rather than the overriding `LambdaSuper.toString()`. It seems that the compiler vendors are careful regarding what to expect from the JRE capabilities and, unfortunately, this part seems to be a bit underspecified.

Still, for real inner class scenarios, they *are* required.

Comment: Interestingly, my test with `javac` revealed that it even generates *two* identical accessor methods for `T.super.toString()`, one being entirely unused.

Comment: Well, Eclipse and javac give totally different results. Eclipse emits 1 accessor and 2 methodrefs to that accessor. While javac emits 2 accessors (one called directly, the other from lambda), and 2 lamda methods, of which one calls an accessor, the other does `invokespecial` on `Object::toString` directly, without an accessor.

Comment: To your answer -- I can accept the need for an accessor in a super class (to bypass an override), but why is it here in the class itself? Since `super.toString()` uses `invokespecial`, not an accessor, why all the other don't do the same?

Comment: Well, `javac` generates multiple accessor methods, because it adds line debug information to it. For the reason, why it doesn't treat `T.super` like `super` when `T` is the current class, the uncomfortable truth is that compilers not always generate the most efficient code.

Comment: For other examples of less than optimal compiler output see  [Why switch on String compiles into two switches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25568639/2711488) or [try with resources introduce unreachable bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25615417/2711488)

Comment: Re 1st paragraph: I think the last sentence should stress that it applies only for invocations on an outer class, that is in the form `T.super.method()`.

Comment: Re `T.super.method()` when invoked in `T`: It seems that a chain of accessors is generated up to the denoted type. In the outer most type accessor, in `T`, the actual method call is contained, while intermediate accessors serve for passing down reference to an immediate outer class. So if `T` is the current class, it's a degenerated case where only the final accessor with a method call will be created.

Comment: For the form `super::toString`, the accessor is created for a completely different reason -- I believe it's a closure capturing the `super` instance, since it's an instance method reference. So this case has nothing to do with bypassing an override.

Comment: And the last case, `T.super::toString` is a combination of the two. :o)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now it's indeed more clear, so I casted an upvote. However, unless my recent findings are wrong, your answer explains only 1.5 of the 3 cases. I'll compile an answer myself and will wait for other readers to react.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "`super` instance". Whether you write `this::toString` or `super::toString`, in both cases, the same instance is captured, only the type of invocation changes. But `this::toString` doesn't need an accessor method. Note that the example code in my answer does exactly the same as `super::toString`, capturing the instance, but without needing an accessor method.

Comment: Which case do you think to be unanswered?

Comment: But, as you wrote, the difference is in invocation type (`invokevirtual` vs `invokespecial`). By `super` instance I meant `invokespecial` on a parent type (with `this` as a target, agreed). So does that Oracle code example translate into `invokespecial` directly **inside** a bootstrap method?

Comment: Eclipse translates `super::toString` into a methodref to an "accessor" that just takes `this` as an argument, while `() -> super.toString()` it translates to a lamda method, which uses `this` directly. OpenJDK uses in both cases the latter.

Comment: Yeah, OpenJDK prefers to always use `static` methods for lambda expressions, even if `this` is captured. Since methods hosting the code of explicit lambda expressions are `private`, that's a minor difference, as it will always be a non-virtual call. And that should answer the other question, yes, the generated classes are capable of doing non-virtual calls, including `private` methods, and in the example, Oracle generates a class which does `invokespecial` with the intended super call semantic directly.

Comment: Re "what was unanswered": Explanation of lines `/*3*/` and `/*4*/` as **closures** being the reason for a synthetic method, especially in the case of `super::toString`, which is not a case of an accessor chain to an outer class. Still I'd like to hear if `invokespecial` is legal in a bootstrap method (as suggested by the Oracle example).

Comment: Actually, that's the opposite: OpenJDK is **not** using **static** methods (that I meant by *"uses `this` directly"*), so it is virtual. That's Eclipse who uses a **static** method, but just in case of a **methodref**, not for a lambda.

Comment: Being closures is *not* the reason. As said, `this::method` is a closure as well and doesn't need such a method. It's all about the accessibility and invocation type. `invokespecial` is always legal if you're invoking a `private` method of your own class, as all lambda expressions are compiled into `private` synthetic methods. Regarding `super` invocations, as said, it's a bit underspecified.

Comment: OK, so at least a "part of the reason"? That `this::method` goes without a need for a synthetic method is apparent. And `super.method()` goes also without. And for Oracle, also `super::method` goes without. So the `invokespecial` can go directly to a bootstrap method (lambda metafactory) and both Eclipse and OpenJDK could also go without an accessor, right? So the reason would be "Eclipse, OpenJDK", not "closure".

Comment: Last question, hopefully: How does Oracle act upon `() -> this.method()`? It should create a lambda method, at last, shouldn't it?

Comment: `() -> this.method()` is always compiled into a lambda method. It would be possible to recognize this pattern and replace it by an equivalent method reference, but 1.) someone has to implement it and create test cases, etc. and 2.) this hypothetical optimization should not apply when line debug attributes are turned on (they are by default) as the source code line number(s) of the lambda expression get attached to that synthetic lambda method.

Answer (score 0):

[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675765/1120854) already explained **why** it is happening — `super` reference is restricted to the immediate child class only. Here's just a more verbose version of what's really happening there:

---

#### Call to an enclosing type's super class' method

```
class T {
    class U {
        class V {{
/*2*/       T.super.toString();
        }}
    }
}
```

It generates a chain of synthetic accessor methods:

```
class T {
    static synthetic String access$0(T t) { // executing accessor
        return t.super.toString(); // only for the refered outer class
    }
    class U { // new U(T.this)
        static synthetic T access$0(U u) { // relaying accessor
            return T.this; // for every intermediate outer class
        }
        class V {{ // new V(U.this)
            T.access$0(U.access$0(U.this)); // T.access$0(T.this)
        }}
    }
}
```

When `T` is the immediately enclosing class, i.e. there are no intermediate outer classes, only the "executing" accessor is generated in class `T` (i.e. in itself, which seems to be unnecessary).

N.B.: The accessor chain is generated by *Eclipse*, but not by *OpenJDK*, see bellow.

---

#### Method reference to own super class' method

```
class T {
    class U {
        class V {{
            Supplier<?> s;
/*3*/       s = super::toString;
        }}
    }
}
```

This generates a synthetic accessor method and a bootstrap method delegating to it:

```
class T {
    class U {
        class V {
            static synthetic String access$0(V v) {
                return v.super.toString();
            }
            dynamic bootstrap Supplier get(V v) { // methodref
                return () -> V.access$0(v); // toString() adapted to get()
            }
            {
                get(V.this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's a singular case similar to the previous one, since `super::toString` is here equivalent to `V.super::toString`, so the synthetic accessor is generated in the class `V` itself. A new element here is the bootstrap method for adapting `Object::toString` to `Supplier::get`.

N.B.: Here only *OracleJDK* is "smart" enough (as [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675765/1120854) pointed out) to avoid the synthetic accessor by placing the `super` call directly into the method reference adapter.

---

#### Method reference to an enclosing type's super class' method

```
class T {
    class U {
        class V {{
            Supplier<?> s;
/*4*/       s = T.super::toString;
        }}
    }
}
```

As you can expect, this is a combination of the two previous cases:

```
class T {
    static synthetic String access$0(T t) { // executing accessor
        return t.super.toString(); // only for the refered outer class
    }
    class U { // new U(T.this)
        static synthetic T access$0(U u) { // relaying accessor
            return T.this; // for every intermediate outer class
        }
        class V { // new V(U.this)
            dynamic bootstrap Supplier get(T t) { // methodref
                return () -> T.access$0(t); // toString() adapted to get()
            }
            {
                get(U.access$0(U.this)); // get(T.this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing really new here, just note that inner class always receives only the instance of the immediate outer class, so in the class `V`, using `T.this` it either might go through the whole chain of intermediate synthetic accessor methods, e.g. `U.access$0(V.U_this)` (as in *Eclipse*), or take the advantage of package visibility of these synthetic fields (that reference `outer.this`) and translate `T.this` to `V.U_this.T_this` (as in *OpenJDK*).

---

N.B.: The above translations are as per *Eclipse* compiler. *OpenJDK* differs in generating **instance** synthetic lambda methods for method references, instead of **static** synthetic accessor methods as *Eclipse* does, and also avoids the accessor chain, so in the last case *OpenJDK* emits:

```
class T {
    static synthetic String access$0(T t) { // executing accessor
        return t.super.toString(); // only for the refered outer class
    }
    class U { // new U(T.this)
        class V { // new V(U.this)
            instance synthetic Object lambda$0() {
                return T.access$0(V.U_this.T_this); // direct relay
            }
            dynamic bootstrap Supplier get(V v) { // methodref
                return () -> V.lambda$0(v); // lambda$0() adapted to get()
            }
            {
                get(V.this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

To sum up, it's quite dependent on the compiler vendor.